# Why isn't there a XmlNode.SelectSingleNode method in windows universal app?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I got a Xml and i want to get single elements by their name. I tried to use the SelectSingelNode-method. This is what MSDN tells you to do:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

At the moment I'm using XmlDocument and XmlNodeList to read the Xml. but this gives me the whole tree.

```
string path = "xml_path.xml";
FileStream reader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(reader);
XmlNodeList node = xdoc.GetElementsByName("name");
```

I can't find the SelectSingeNode method in win-universal-app. i am using Visual Studio 2015. Why did they remove this? Is there another way of getting a single element by it's name?

Comment: XmlNodeList is enumerable so you can just do .First() or .FirstorDefault or use Where to filter and pick specific name element

Comment: There also isn't a method called .First of .FirstOrDefault for XmlNodeList, only FirstChild which returns the first ChildNode, not selectable by name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XmlNodeList is Enumerable but it does not implement Generic IEnumerable so you have to Cast it before you can use Linq query to solve your problem

```
XmlNode node = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("name").Cast<XmlNode>().First();
XmlNode node = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("name").Cast<XmlNode>().FirstorDefault();
XmlNode node = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("name").Cast<XmlNode>().Where(somecondition).FirstorDefault();
```

Comment: GetElementsByName("name") doesn't work for me. It's GetElementsByTagName. There is also an error message for the cast which say: "XmlNodeList does not contain a definition for 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlNodeList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Thomas did you have `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: I had using System.Xml.Linq instead of System.Linq. Sorry for that and thank you!!